# How can I make the Dial window close automatically when connection is complete?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

:Dial
Rasdial Connection_Name Username Password
if errorlevel 1 goto Dial

The above commands are in a .bat file. How can I make the Dial window close automatically when connection is complete?

Comment: Try sticking `Exit` at the end of the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Exit` to the end of your batch file to instruct it to end the batch script, this closing the current command prompt.

[More info on Exit](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)